# Any use of declaring a private static class in c#?

Tags: c#

Is there any use of declaring a static class as private.Here is the code below:

```
static class DerivedClass
{
    private static string GetVal()
    {
        return "Hello";
    }
}
```

Comment: Encapsulation and clear intent?

Comment: the same use as for a public static class, but then used locally (internally).

Comment: You don't need `asp.net` tag for this question.

Comment: @bas how 2 use it locally when its private?

Comment: In your example the class is public and the `string` is private.

Comment: Your code won't compile, unless it's a nested class. Is it a nested class?

Comment: @iBlue, did you try it? because you'll get a compiler error when you use the code you just edited in your question

Comment: @bas Not if the class is nested in another class.

Comment: well as i believe if class access modifer is not declared it would be treated as private in c# 3.0, so it would compile

Comment: iBlue, your note is incorrect. According to the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms173121(v=vs.80).aspx) **Classes and structs that are not nested within other classes or structs can be either public or internal ... Classes and structs are declared as internal by default**

Comment: @p.s.w.g thnks i guess i misunderstood dat :), but one doubt u said it can be either public or internal, does it depend on something

Comment: @svick, fair enough. it would help if op mentioned nested classes in either text or code ex.

Comment: @iBlue it depends on the access modifier that you use.

Comment: i mean if i don't declare a access modifier, then u said it would be either public or internal.So when would it be public and when internal

Comment: @iBlue (google, msdn) Classes and structs that are declared directly within a namespace (in other words, that are not nested within other classes or structs) can be either public or internal. Internal is the default if no access modifier is specified.

Comment: Why is there a static class called "DerivedClass"?  Isn't that confusing? Static classes are not allowed to be derived classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sample code you provided actually illustrates an internal class, not a private class. This is perfectly fine and is done all the time. It means the methods of the class are available from other classes within the same module, but not externally.

If you mean declaring private members of static classes, sure there is.

```
static class DerivedClass
{
    public static string GetVal()
    {
        return GetValInternal();
    }

    private static string GetValInternal()
    {
        return "Hello";
    }
}
```

If you mean declaring a private static nested classes (because only nested classes can be private, according to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms173121%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)), then you can do it, but there's probably no reason to do it.

```
class SomeClass
{
    private static class DerivedClass
    {
        public static string GetVal()
        {
            return "Hello";
        }
    }
}
```

Is equivalent to

```
class SomeClass
{
    private static string GetVal()
    {
        return "Hello";
    }
}
```

Comment: i mean the class not methods

Answer (score 1):

By default classes with no access modifiers like in your example are *internal*, not *private*. See this reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx. This means that you can access this class from anywhere inside the library/project. This makes sense because it allows you to use the class internally without necessarily exposing it to the outside world.

Explicitly declaring it as *private* however makes sense in some rare cases only in my opinion. I have used it before for nested classes simply to group certain things together and make my code prettier/more readable. However I find that if I am creating nested classes it usually means that I need to redesign my code and pull some of it into separate files and separate classes. Rather try to stick to one class per file.